# How do I change the width of the modal? its too small. react-responsive-modal

Tags: reactjs, react-responsive-modal

How do I change the width of the modal? its too small

[image]

```
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal';

 <Modal style={{"width": "800px"}} open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal}>


 </Modal>
```

Answer (score 1):

style prop is wrong, change it to styles.
Refer to the documentaion:
[react-responsive-modal](https://react-responsive-modal.leopradel.com/#props)

```
<Modal styles={{modal: { width: "800px"}}}></Modal>
```